# How do I save a list of arrays (frames) to a video using OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy, opencv

I have tried to save a list of arrays to a video using the following code, but it isn't working.

```py
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (1280, 720))
for frame in frames:
    out.write(frame) # frame is a numpy.ndarray with shape (1280, 720, 3)
out.release()
```

It fails with no error message, but the output file (output.mp4) is around 200 bytes long and doesn't open in QuickTime or VLC. My assumption is that `out.write` is somehow failing silently. Is it possible to write arrays to a video in this way? If not, how could it be done?

Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check your frame size? Most probably the creates the problem

Comment: I believe the frame size is correct, but I will double check. Thanks.

Comment: Try this  ```out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (720, 1080))```

Comment: It would seem the x and y axis were switched in the numpy array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I made a formal answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy array is (row,column) but OpenCV defines images by (width,height). So, in your numpy array `height=row=1080` and `width=column=720`. So,
Change the frame size (1080,720) to (720,1080).

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, (720, 1080))
for frame in frames:
    out.write(frame) # frame is a numpy.ndarray with shape (1280, 720, 3)
out.release()
```